# Getting network interface device name in powershell

Tags: powershell

I needed a powershell 2 script to get the name and device name of each interface like it is shown in network connections in control panel.

Should be easy...

```
$interfaces = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter
$interfaces | foreach {
    $friendlyname = $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NetConnectionID
    $name = $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    "$friendlyname is $name"
}
```

However, $name comes back as "Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (NDIS VBD Client)", whereas in control panel it shows "Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (NDIS VBD Client) **#69**", because there are multiple cards.  I can't find that number anywhere in the properties.

How can I get both the Name and Device Name, exactly as shown in Network Connections, in powershell 2 on windows server 2008 r2?

Update:  The really weird thing is it shows the # part for other kinds of network cards - the interfaces for teamed cards show it properly.  My nvidia based ones show it on my desktop system.  Maybe it's only the broadcom cards?  The server in question is a Dell R715, with 4 onboard broadcom nics, and a 4 port broadcom addon card.

After testing on some more systems (and commenter's tests on their systems), it appears to be a "feature" of the broadcom drivers.  Updating the drivers didn't change anything.

What ways are there, **besides Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter** to get both the Name and Device Name of all the network adapters in a system?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking for the `DeviceID`?

Comment: DeviceID isn't the right spot.  However, I just checked, and double checked, and when I run this on my machines, the Name property is properly showing #2 at the end of the adapter name.  Description shows it as just the adapter name.

Comment: The funny thing is that it does show the #x for SOME adapters...the virtual adapters for teaming show the numbers properly.  But the actual broadcom interfaces don't.

Comment: On the systems here it's exactly the opposite. Teamed adapters don't show the numbers, while standalone adapters do. You should be able to retrieve the complete names from the registry, though. Look in the subkeys of `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\EBDRV]`.

Comment: Have you tried Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration

Comment: @ShawnMelton yes, unfortunately it is missing the number part as well.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers on my system it's under CurrentControlSet\Enum\B06BDRV...is there any way to reliably match the WMI information to it's registry entry?

Comment: @Grant Maybe with something like `Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty | where { $_.FriendlyName -match "Broadcom .* NetXtreme" }`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, found the solution!  Since it does show up correctly in the registry and device manager, we can get it from the related Win32_PnPEntity object.  So the code becomes:

```
$interfaces = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter
$interfaces | foreach {
    $friendlyname = $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NetConnectionID
    $name = $_.GetRelated("Win32_PnPEntity") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    "$friendlyname is $name"
}
```

This matches perfectly with the names in device manager and network connections on all of the systems I have tried it on.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is your whole code, but with your current loop, you are just writing over the `$friendlyname` and the `$name` variables.  It might be that the last item was the one without the number on it.  The following code gave me the results you are looking for:

```
$interfaces = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter
$Outputs = @()
foreach ($Interface in $Interfaces) { 
    $Output = New-Object -TypeName System.Object
    $Output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FriendlyName -Value $Interface.NetConnectionID
    $Output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Interface.Name
    $Outputs += $Output
}
```

You can then use `$outputs | out-grid` to see all that was listed on your system.

Comment: its not the whole code, just the broken bits.  the loop actually does stuff with the variables.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Then I'm not sure, because the `Name` field shows the number on my system.  I'm testing on Windows 7 though, so it might have something to do with different OS's

Comment: I'm actually thinking it's a driver issue.

Answer (score 2):

When attempting the answer from Grant I got some errors indicating I was attempting to print a null variable. Here is the workaround:

```
$interfaces = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter
$interfaces | ForEach{
    $friendlyname = $_ | ForEach-Object { $_.NetConnectionID }
    $name = $_.GetRelated("Win32_PnPEntity") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    # This tests to ensure friendlyname isn't null
    if($friendlyname){
        "$friendlyname is $name"
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense to add that If statement. thx.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a way to list only PHYSICAL device names:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE Manufacturer != 'Microsoft' AND NOT PNPDeviceID LIKE 'ROOT\\%'"
$interfaces = Get-WmiObject -Query $query | Sort index
$interfaces | ForEach{
    $friendlyname = $_ | ForEach-Object { $_.NetConnectionID }
    $name = $_.GetRelated("Win32_PnPEntity") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    # This tests to ensure friendlyname isn't null
    if($friendlyname){
        "$friendlyname is $name"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Ethernet is Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (6) Is19-LM
Wi-Fi is Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 X200 160MHz
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this on Windows10:

```
Get-NetAdapter -Name * | %{ $_.name }

# Ethernet
```

You can find more examples on [Get-NetAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapter?view=windowsserver2022-ps#examples)

Comment: You don't need the `-Name *`, that's the default. And you don't need the `Foreach-Object` loop either, you can use `(Get-NetAdapter).Name` directly.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks for your note, but what if I have multiple interfaces? I need to list them all.

Comment: It's the default to list all interfaces.

Comment: Great! I found this from docs.microsoft actually.